# Crop a moving screen from a video

Tags: tracking

I am completely lost on how to even word what I want, but here goes.

I have a video clip of someone holding a screen up to a camera, what I want to do is track all four corners of the held screen and crop/transform/stretch it to the entire view. Like a really bad screen grab.

Apologies if this is a duplicate, I have searched high and low and just can't find what I'm looking for. Maybe it's just my wording. Links to any resources/videos that can help me would also be greatly appreciated.

:)

Comment: Hmm you want the plane tracker I think but use it to invert distortion back to full screen? Maybe by usnig the UV node?

Comment: Okay, so I have done the tracking, and set up the Plane Tracking and I have a box following the screen around as accurately as I am happy with. What would be my next step?

Comment: I feel like the corner pin node might get me somewhere. It seems to do what I think needs doing. Just unsure how to get/how I would use the tracked positions of the plane tracker.

Comment: Yeah you can't, you'll have to just use the tracker positions. Turn them into tracked empties in the Solve panel. What you want to do is UV map the region bounded by the tracked markers then distort the resulting plane into a full screen. But I tried and have no answers sorry.

Comment: Okay, thanks for helping. It's a start regardless.